# How to add the error type of useQueries in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, react-query

I'm using `react-query`'s [`useQueries`](https://tanstack.com/query/v4/docs/reference/useQueries) to define a custom hook `useArtists`:

```
type SuccessResponse = {
  artist: {
    name: string
  }
};


const fetchArtist = async (artistId: string): Promise<SuccessResponse> => {
  const response = await axios.get(`/artists/${artistId}`);

  if (response.status !== 200) {
    throw response.data.error ?? "Unknown error";
  }

  return response.data;
};


export const useArtists = (artistIds: string[]) => {
  return useQueries({
    queries: artistIds.map((artistId) => {
      return {
        queryKey: ["artists", artistId],
        queryFn: () => fetchArtist(artistId),
      };
    }),
  });
};
```

The inferred return type of `useArtists` is `UseQueryResult<SuccessResponse, unknown>[]`.

How could I add the return type of the error, which is `string`, so that the return type becomes `UseQueryResult<SuccessResponse, string>[]`?

Comment: I was hoping useQueries might let you specify the success return type as generics but it doesn't appear as though. I tried to get this running on stackblitz without success: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-yacnui?file=App.tsx

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can provide types to `useQueries` by annotating `queries` you're passing to `useQueries`. In your example, this can be done by passing a generic to the `.map` itself:

```
type Artist = { name: string }

export const useArtists = (artistIds: string[]) => {
  return useQueries({
    queries: artistIds.map<UseQueryOptions<Artist[], Error>>((artistId) => {
      return {
        queryKey: ["artists", artistId],
        queryFn: () => fetchArtist(artistId),
      };
    }),
  });
};
```

`UseQueryOptions` can be imported from `@tanstack/react-query`, and it's the

Here's a working [TypeScript Playground](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/JYWwDg9gTgLgBAKjgQwM5wEoFNkGN4BmUEIcA5FDvmQNwBQokscA3nAK6pYCK7WUwLKgA0cAKpde-AJ4B5MDGAQAdugC+cIiXIABGMlX7cAawD0lPDAC0ARz5RpZOnQLtl+JcrgBBMGAAUAJSsznBwMNJgWD6wwKjwALyscMrIIFgAXHDxAsoA5nBqoXC4KvGaWDC4ABbeseVJ-sj1MACSACZZOcD5gVl1ivEA2gC6cAkAfCFhYZQw7FBeo-RhavR0YaWGHFwDcTDojc2Dbe2oXTC5eaPBk9MzcwtenDz2gqj+LBszYXb871ljvsOqgAHQgZBgAA8EleMnkijKUL2wxGogAolBiFAJhN-E0Wh1blMvj8fo9FvcyTM-g4ANJYaRZIZkIHxVBkURs05o77U372aQAMWUWSC4ymBEqNRRMAJJyJwj5-PiyAANlgACqgTJwVrKAg9YARJX8worMlqQKmmZWi1rYpbcrc8Y7LCyj43C2mUw-AB6AH5vhSvP5lVD2sAAG4TZVhKHVACMEwAElg1WqIHAAMpGYwAITVxoAXgBCKGmJOx6lQsATFgAKWzsgAcqDuvlgARpPL9oE1BW6+HTJGY99AvQikA).